# Installing LabVIEW Community Edition 2022 on Ubunt Mate 22.04

Tags: package-management

I'm a new user of Ubuntu Mate 22.04

I've tried to install LabVIEW Community Edition. Installation script failed with this error message:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ni-wine : Depends: libncurses5 but it is not installable
Depends: libldap-2.4-2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Un-registering ubuntu Feed

How can I correct the missing dependencies?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Are you sure the app you are trying to install will run on this version of the OS?

Comment: LabVIEW is built by National Instruments. The WEB Page of the community edition of LabVIEW lists "Ubuntu" as one of the supported OS. No more detail, unfortunately

Comment: Actually National Instruments says, Ubuntu 20 is supported

Comment: I suggest then some research and or contact them. Where did you get the app you are trying to install?

Comment: That would mean Ubuntu  Core 20 as all other versions of Ubuntu have more then 1 digit as a version number. They might mean Ubuntu 20.04 but 22.04 is newer and different.

Comment: The version of [`libldap`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libldap-2.5-0) available for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS or the 2022-April release is 2.5 and not 2.4.  The version you've grabbed appears very old (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libldap) and appears to be unmaintained from what you've pasted. A quick glance at `libcurses5` shows it being available in 'universe' (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libncurses5&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) so do you have 'universe' enabled (ie. community packages)

Comment: If it was intended for 20; you install using `snap install` and don't use `apt` and don't have the dependency issues that *deb* packages contain. Are you sure it supported 20, and if it was 20 & not 20.04 then you should have no issues on 22.04 as it runs the identical *snap* packages as 16, 18, 20 and 22 all run; ie. no dependency issues (20 & 20.04 are different products)

Comment: Download from : [https://www.ni.com/de-at/support/downloads/software-products/download.labview-community.html#460310] Readme file quoting Ubuntu 20 [https://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/lv-2022-q3-linux.html]

Comment: The detail where it came from should be in your question (*that's what will be answered; comments are for us to ask questions of you & comments will be removed once addressed*).  Yes it does say Ubuntu 18 & 20, which highlights to me a lack of understanding/detail and low quality in whomever wrote the docs, thus errors are likely due to lack of knowledge/detail in whomever packaged/wrote up the docs.